# Determining top margin for content when using bootstrap 4 fixed top bar nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 fixed top nav bar as my main menu. I know that using fixed bar, I can clear the upcoming content by giving it a top margin that is equal to the height of the fixed nav bar. The problem is that since I use bootstrap, it is creating an adaptive layout, so I don't know what the height of the fixed nav bar would be in advance. What can I do in this situation?

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light fixed-top">
```

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle link so that it will be easy to solve because its working in my scenario

Comment: @Thinker I am sorry. I never used jsfiddle. Can you just give the high level idea?

Comment: Try to use `.sticky-top` for the nav-bar instead off `fixed-top`

Comment: @Thinker What is the difference?